# setting hadoop job configuration programmatically

Tags: configuration, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting OOM exception (Java heap space) for reduce child. I read in the documentation that increasing the value of `mapred.reduce.child.java.opts` to -Xmx512M or more would help. Since I am not the admin, I cannot change that value in mapred-site.xml. I would like to set that value only for my job through the java program. I tried setting it using `Configuration` class as follows, but that didn't work.

`Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.set("mapred.reduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx512M");
JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(config, this.getClass());`

The version of Hadoop is 1.0.3

What is the proper way of setting the configuration values programmatically?

Comment: That actually works like this (if you are using the old API mapper and reducer).

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Sorry, but, how does it work? I didn't understand the comment "works like this".

Comment: Like you've posted there. How do you check if the memory is not set correctly?

Comment: you should check, that mapred.reduce.child.java.opts is not marked 'final' in server mapred-site.xml. if it is marked, you not be able to change it

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Ok. Your question made me check the value of "mapred.child.java.opts" using config.get("mapred.child.java.opts") and I got the correct value of -Xmx200m. So I think I am setting it the proper way, but may be 512m is not sufficient. I tried with 1024m and I got heap space error again. I read that "mapred.child.java.opts" is for pre 1.0.3 versions. Is that correct?

Comment: @octo I actually don't find mapred.reduce.child.java.opts in the mapred-site.xml. mapred.child.java.opts is present, but I read on the net that this is for pre 1.0 hadoop versions.

Comment: @Raghava both options work in post 1.0 versions. mapred.child.java.opts marked as deprecated, but should work (can't recall, which one has higher precedence)

Comment: @octo Ok. I tried both. I set both of them to -Xmx1024m. But I still get the heap space error. Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: check, that property was actually set. examine job.xml of the job via web interface.

Comment: @octo Both the properties are set to -Xmx1024m in the job.xml of the job

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the OOM, or are you able to advise where in the reduce stage you're getting the OOM. Are you using custom writables - maybe there's a problem with your readFields method? or are you accumulating the values for a particular key into a set in your reduce method?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes, I am accumulating the values - I am appending the values to a StringBuilder, which would be the output of reduce. I think it is better to make this as a new question. I will provide the link to that SO post here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831076/oom-exception-in-hadoop-reduce-child Made it into a separate question

Answer (score 0):

AS @ThomasJungblut and @octo have pointed out, the procedure I mentioned in the question is the right way of doing it. The OOM exception still persists, so I would start a new thread instead of continuing here.